# I am using nodejs version 20.10.0, but I am getting error that says you are using node js 15.0.1

Tags: next.js, nodevm

I am trying to build nexjs app, but once I run `npm run dev` the cmd is giving me the following error

```
You are using Node.js 15.0.1. For Next.js, Node.js version >= v18.17.0 is required.
```

actually I am using nodejs `v20.10.0`

when I run `node -v`, it shows `v20.10.0`
I don't know why, can any one help me figure out?

Comment: I am not sure what is the issue here, but one possibility is that what you're seeing might not be the actual Node.js version. Sometimes, other programs or command line tools might override or the version. If you are not using the NVM then install NVM and fire command `nvm use v20.10.0`. And then try to run your nextjs app using `npm run dev`.

Comment: I downloaded the nodejs v20.10.0 from the nodejs website and installed it, I don't thinks that this is the problem

Comment: check: 1. if both the error and `node -v` command are run in same terminal or different. 2. restart terminal. Also paste screenshot here if still not solved

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few steps you can take to troubleshoot and resolve this issue:-

**1.Clear Node.js Cache:-**

Sometimes, caching issues can cause discrepancies. Try clearing the Node.js cache with the following commands:-

```
> npm cache clean -f
```

**2. Reinstall Dependencies:-**

If you've made changes to the Node.js version or other configurations, consider reinstalling the project dependencies:

```
> rm -rf node_modules npm install
```

***Also, Crosscheck Your Nodejs environment.***